# Please explain the use of Ember.$?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Please could someone explain why I see examples of people using Ember.$ for jQuery rather than $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just jQuery attached to Ember's namespace.  Same as jQuery.  Maybe someday if Ember was feeling like removing the dependency on jQuery they could implement some of the functionality, but I remember Tom and Yehuda saying there was no point in re-implementing jQuery, it already does it's job really well.

Here's the code that does it:

```
init: function() {
    if (!this.$) { this.$ = jQuery; }
```

Comment: Are there benefits to using this pattern?

Comment: Nah, same as just using $.  Takes at least three extra keys while typing (shorthand Em === Ember, Em.$)

Comment: @Chris Maybe when you would have other library than jQuery attached to `$`.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 $ in ember and they both link to jQuery internally.

There is a global one Ember.$. The goal is the be able to replace jquery if needed in the future.

There is also one for each view instance (this.$()) which points to the jquery element used by the view:

```
...
didInsertElement: function(){
  alert(this.$().position().top);
}
...
```

This is equivalent of doing Em.$(this.element). If you pass a selector, it will scope the selection to the view element only so this.$(".selector") is the same as Em.$(this.element, ".selector").